# some html entities rendering as ? on web page

Tags: php, mysql, apache, encoding, html-entities

I have a web application that is having trouble rending some html entities properly.  I'm stumped.  Some very commonly used ones such as

```
&lt; and &quote;
```

and others for building html are just fine.  But others like

```
&deg; or &plusmn; or even &nbsp;
```

are rendering as the � character.  The pages and the databases (mysql) are all set to UTF-8 and unicode general.  This is happening on an Ubuntu server running apache and php. Chrome using Detect Encoding recognizes it as UTF-8.

I have a development copy of the app and the same data running on my Macbook using MAMP and it doesn't exhibit this problem.  Stumped.

Comment: Just for reference: [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: &xxx; -- this is an "html entity".  Where did your data come from.

Comment: What was the black diamond supposed to be?

Comment: Yes, they are html entities, as stated.  Mostly they came from end users typing/pasting text into a form with TinyMCE providing an editor.  However it's an old app, and odd characters are converted into html entities prior to storage in MySQL.  Suffice to say, they are simple text html entities.  The diamond character above, as I said, are the deg, plusmn and nbsp entities.